# Como hacer que se repita todo luego de terminar la condicional

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
age = input()
if int(age) >= 18: 
    print ("you can do it")
else:
     print ("you can't do it")
```

Comment: creo que se te quedó la pregunta a medias

Comment: Podrías aclarar mas la pregunta, pero de antemano para repetir parte de un código se usa la estructura de while(condicion):

Comment: A ver. Luego de que se ejecute todo. Que se comienza a ejecutar de nuevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un while  podrías repetirlo, la pregunta seria hasta cuándo.
Escribiendo while True (no aconsejado) se repetirá constantemente:

```
while True:
    age = input()
    if int(age) >= 18: 
        print ("you can do it")
    else:
        print ("you can't do it")
```

Comment: Eso hace que se repita constantemente. Como desde ahí hago que un ejemplo cuando se repita 1000 veces se detenga?

Comment: con un bucle for in:

Comment: for x in range(1000): sentencias

Comment: Como pongo el bucle para todo por qué en el bucle for es a una variable . No sé si lo pondría a age o que?. Por favor explícame tomando de referencia la porción de código que escribí. Soy principiante.

Comment: x solo haría que el bucle se repita por cada uno de sus valores hasta 1000, si mal no me equivoco. El código seía el siguiente según lo que entiendo:

Comment: for x in range(1000): # comienza el bucle a repetirse por cada x de la lista de 1000 números generada por range(1000)
    age = input()
    if int(age) >= 18: 
        print ("you can do it")
    else:
        print ("you can't do it")